# Multiple forms to have specific Flask Flash messages per form on page

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have multiple forms on a page and would like to flash specific messages based on the form. I cant seem to find any answers online for this so was hoping someone could point me in the direction of enlightment or offer any guidance.

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umair Magbool's comment made me think of adding a prefix to the messages based on the form that submitted them. I tested this out by adding a value to the flash:

```
flash('add_root_submit: Administrator account updated successfully!', 'success')
```

I then checked for this new input during the html render:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            {% if 'add_root_submit' in message %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}" role="alert">
                    {{ message|replace('add_root_submit: ', '') }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}   
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

This has worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the messages which are to appear on a page you can write code like below:

```
{% if error == "Something here" %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
{% endif %}

{% if msg == "Something here" %}
    <div class="alert alert-success">{{msg}}</div>
{% endif %}

{% if msg == "Something here" %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning">{{msg}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Arr yes, I wonder if it is possible to append something to the messages depending on the form it came from? Im using the default validators and form. `form.validate_on_submit()`. I think I will try something similar to `flash('"Form Name Here:" Administrator account updated successfully!', 'success')`

Comment: Yes you have to use it like this : flash("your message" , "success")